# Identifying unused files on web server

Tags: linux, bash, operating-system, filesystems, data-cleaning

How can I identify which files are safe for deletion and which files need to kept around?

After running STAT all files were accessed as of yesterday but there are many files which haven't actually been used in years.

What methodology is best for determining which files are good to go?

Perhaps using PHP to create a hiercharchy list of how all files are called/referenced? Unfortunately with Accessed dates all screwed up I can't use that as a determining factor but I suppose I could also include Modify/Change date.

Anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what applications are active on that server. I don't think anyone can give you an answer without knowing what your server is used for. There may be some configuration files (e.g., php.ini) that haven't been modified in years but are still needed.

Answer (score 1):

As for files that are directly publicly accessible via http or https (such as .php files, html files, etc), your web server log files might be useful in determining how frequently these files have been accessed in recent weeks/months.